# Conditional dataframe manipulation by row

Tags: python, r, pandas, dfply

Say I have a df like

[image: sample dataframe]

and I want a df like this

[image]

How would I do this in python or R?  This would be so easy in excel with a simple if statement, for example: c5 =IF(c2 = "X", "ccc", c4).

I thought this would be simple in R too, but I tried
df <- df %>% mutate(c4 = ifelse(c2 = 'X', paste(c3, c3, c3), c4)),
and it fills all the other values with NA's:

[image]

Why is this happening and how would I fix it?

Ideally though, I'd like to do this in python.  I've tried dfply's mutate and ifelse similarly to the above, and using pandas loc function, but neither have worked.

This feels like it should be really simple - is there something obvious that I'm missing?

Answer (score 0):

We may need `strrep` in `R`

```
library(dplyr)
df %>%
   mutate(c4 = ifelse(c2 %in% "X", strrep(c3, nchar(c4)), c4))
```

-output

```
  id c2 c3  c4
1  1     a aaa
2  2     b bbb
3  3  X  c ccc
```

#### data

```
df <- structure(list(id = 1:3, c2 = c("", "", "X"), c3 = c("a", "b", 
"c"), c4 = c("aaa", "bbb", "zzz")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-3L))
```

Comment: Ok, that handles the repeating string piece (thank you!), but not the rest.  It is still yielding NA's for me, which I don't understand.  I'm not getting the same output you are.

Comment: @user276238 I am assuming that you have `NA` in your c2 column instead of blanks (`""`).  Just change the `==` to `%in%` and it should work.  Please find the update

Answer (score 0):

```py
df.c4.where(df.c2.ne("X"), other=df.c3 * 3)
```

This reads as

"for `c4` column: *where* the `c2` values are *n*ot *e*qual to "X", keep them as is; otherwise, put the 3-times repeated `c3` values".

Example run:

```py
In [182]: df
Out[182]:
   id c2 c3   c4
0   1     a  aaa
1   2     b  bbb
2   3  X  c  zzz

In [183]: df.c4 = df.c4.where(df.c2.ne("X"), other=df.c3 * 3)

In [184]: df
Out[184]:
   id c2 c3   c4
0   1     a  aaa
1   2     b  bbb
2   3  X  c  ccc
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you can just do in pandas:

```
m = df['c2'] == 'X'
df.loc[m, 'c4'] = df.loc[m, 'c3'].str.repeat(3)
```

Look for rows whose 'c2' is 'X' and locate 'c3' column , repeat it 3 times and modify the 'c4' column inplace with .loc